# Web Api, howto improve performance with ProtoBuf

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, protocol-buffers

It takes nearly 50 seconds to load a big chunk of 35 MB Json when accessing the Api. So to improve performance I added the WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf to my project. The data is displayed in a Kendo UI Grid.

What am I missing here? A dataType or type in the View, or anything like that? And are there other or better ways to improve the performance?

Here some snippets->

POCO-Class:

```
[ProtoContract]
    public partial class KDAuftraege
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int AngebotsNummer { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public Nullable<int> BesuchsNummer { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public Nullable<int> Kennummer { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
```

View:

```
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '/api/WebApiAuftraege'

            },
        },
```

Controller:

```
public IQueryable<KDAuftraege> GetKDAuftraeges()
    {
        //return db.KDAuftraeges.Take(500);
        return db.KDAuftraeges;
    }
```

WebApi:

```
 config.Formatters.Add(new ProtoBufFormatter());
```

Headers:

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  36227588
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 07 Jun 2014 09:23:54 GMT
Expires -1
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcb2xkc3BvcnRcZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xWaXM0XFZpczRcYXBpXFdlYkFwaUF1ZnRyYWVnZQ==?=
Anfrage-HeaderQuelltext anzeigen
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  __RequestVerificationToken=wMVQWPOkXsB2XDIFN_07RJDtKqN_90dLRYaBYJGsFSGEHTcQ1S6e15mPiWrvkMHS8HrAlHYAI0OVSkqtPQHFVMP5DxoyccijSktL_KsoEFU1; .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=RTQ61CfArDWHlWN06eOpZiZY6NmFGp0SwCCuR8bQCtnItSz6S8YTasQu4-uoRQCc-XqWDCZmtOpEb-b0SyIioQPomkm1BrKywMcVwt3bF_JBxORKGg-UNSHyPvFyBohiS1sJ354LpRHIjrPIA8rUexvZih4VrK9lvHu_sm21ncNXXV7jATKAjTdX7J3XvfxRsF11fhgDNtpXPEWxQPjD7Rkj5yvdqI-vbfr9tfQbszUR1O3oOjYcRxUvvVrJ7xnt-caxt-o_Kut1dixLEA241pMGPCHfetWK73Yp148K3X9By6ylHFOTEjjDwHZyHLIrBwwOZ-ujnaOf20jQzeZXaF16bHxeadLYuKK-Z2DpdzaJXPzZd2pBbzHJMFX7USfZmp7OZzLpOitLCMovGHwdRiLD0F2NR1a0iTHCgiZLvA8
Host    localhost:19275
Referer http://localhost:19275/MvcAuftraege
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Can you post the headers of your request / response? Is `Accept: application/x-protobuf` being set?

Comment: I updated the headers. Where must I actually set `Accept: application/x-protobuf`?

Comment: Looks like it's set to `*/*` allowing the server to pick the encoding, and my guess is the proto buffer encoding is the last option. Could try removing all other formatters (`config.Formatters.Clear();`)then adding the proto-buf formatter. Alternatively, changing your request in your javascript to set it (sorry I'm not familiar with that)

Comment: Have you looked at using IIS compression? If you are using self hosting, you could also look at compressing using a `DelegateHandler`. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/557232/Implementing-a-Custom-DelegatingHandler-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @Aron: I will first get into the content of IIS compression, and then give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Options 1: Change your view DataSource code (I think this is right)

```
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: 'GET',
            headers: { Accept: 'application/x-protobuf' },
            url: '/api/WebApiAuftraege'
        },
    },
```

Option 2: Change your Web API Formatters so that ProtoBuf is the default:

```
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new ProtoBufFormatter());
```

Comment: For option 2 (and this isn't to suggest you should use option 2). Instead do `config.Formatters.Insert(0, new ProtoBufFormatter());`

Comment: @Aron I knew there was a way to insert.. updating my answer and upvoted comment.

Comment: I tried both options. Only Option 2 worked for me (with Aron's suggestion). The type has changed now to `application/x-protobuf`, and the filesize went down to 10 MB. BUT: loading time is still the same-> 50 seconds.

Comment: @oldsport Rule number one of perf. Get statistics first. Try using fiddler to see how long it takes for the first byte to start downloading. You could actually have issues with EF/SQL instead or lots of other pipeline points. It could also be that it takes 50seconds for your UI to update.